# How do I list my activities in Google+ with the API?

Tags: google-plus

How do I see a list of my Google+ activities through the API? I couldn't find a method in the [API Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [link to the API Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=activities.list&userId=me&collection=public&alt=json) with the activities list configured to display all of your activities.

Since the `me` userId is your private data, you'll need to click on the OAuth 2.0 switch in the upper right side of the screen and authorize the API Explorer to know who you are on Google+ before submitting the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, with the [Google-provided php client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/), it looks like this:

```
$collection = 'public';
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setDeveloperKey($api_key);
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);
//$person = $plus->people->get($plus_id);
$results = $plus->activities->listActivities($plus_id, $collection);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But does it return previous +1s on google-plus posts in activity list? What I want is the list of this page:  https://plus.google.com/apps/activities. I am using `me` as the scope.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that; also with G+ being ... deprecated?  I think it's better to just move on, to something else.